# JavaScript Object.Observe delegation

Tags: javascript, object.observe

I have JavaScript array which is consists of many objects.

```
var array=[{name:1},{name:2}.....]
```

I want to use `Object.observe`  to handle data changes on each of these objects.

Is there any way to apply something like event delegation here , in order to not apply `observe` for each of objects?

If I use `Object.observe` for array itself than changing its items doesn't trigger anything.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/aheckmann/observed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, that's not possible.**

Imagine code like this:

```
var foo = {...};
var bar = [foo, {..}, {..}, {..}]
Object.yourWeirdMagicObserve(bar, ..);
```

Would changing `foo` trigger your callback now? Or only modifications to `bar[0]`? When you use `bar[0]` the object is retrieved from `bar` but besides that it has no association with `bar` whatsoever.